# Matlab: static class members

Tags: matlab, list, class, static

I am trying to implement a list which would work as an instance counter in Matlab. I wish this list to be static.

So far, there's no static keyword in matlab, but they provide a pattern which almost do the job:

Declare a class List that inherit handle:

```
classdef List < handle

   properties (Access = private)
      cellRepresentingAList = {};
   end

   ..... %Implement any functions

end
```

Then you can use it the following way:

```
classdef MyClassUsingAList < handle

    properties (Constant, Access = private)
       myListOfStuff = List();
    end

    .....

 end
```

The fact that we are using an handle object as constant leads to the fact that every instance of MyClassUsingAList will use the same object handle, aka I have a static List.

Everything is working perfectly fine until I run into an exception. Or I debug and cease to debug using the "stop debug" button, or save. At this moment, the list is CLEARED. Empty.

This is not something I can put into production.

Matlab offers persistent variable, which play the role of static variables in functions, but it's not possible to use them in a class (unless you use the keyword 'persistent' in every method using the list).

Is there any reliable method to achieve this goal ?

Thanks

Comment: Precision: this seems to happen every time I save the file describing the class which contains the static list. 
Which is less bad than I first expected. 

However, any better solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the `persistent` keyword, as described [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-data.html). (you went for the second approach, I would argue that what you need is this one). You can lock the functions from accidentally being cleared in the event of something like what you describe using the `mlock` commands.

Note that you would *not* have to define a persistent variable in each method as you say! (in fact, that would probably have the opposite effect to what you intend, since the persistent variable is unique to each function, rather than to the class as a whole). Simply create a single method with static access whose whole point is to keep a copy of that persistent variable, and reference that method in any other non-static methods that need to get or set it.

E.g.

```
classdef myclass

  properties
    Prop1;
    Prop2;
  end

  methods(Static, Access='public')
    function Out = StaticVar1(In)   % first static "variable"
      mlock
      persistent var;
      if isempty(var); var = 0; end          % initial value
      if nargin < 1; Out = var; return; end  % get value
      var = In;                              % set value
    end
    function Out = StaticVar2(In)   % second static "variable"
      mlock
      persistent var;
      if isempty(var); var = 0; end          % initial value
      if nargin < 1; Out = var; return; end  % get value
      var = In;                              % set value
    end
  end

  methods
    function Out = addStaticVars(o)
      Out = o.StaticVar1 + o.StaticVar2;
    end
  end
end
```

Example use:

```
>> a = myclass();
>> myclass.StaticVar1       % access the first static "variable"
ans =
     0
>> myclass.StaticVar2       % access the second static "variable"
ans =
     0
>> myclass.StaticVar1(10)   % set static "variable" to 10
>> myclass.StaticVar2(20)   % set static "variable" to 20
>> a.addStaticVars()        
ans =
    30
>> b = myclass();
>> b.addStaticVars()
ans =
    30

>> clear all;               % inneffective as functions are "locked"
>> myclass.StaticVar1
ans =
    10

>> munlock myclass.StaticVar1
>> clear all;        % this will now succeed in clearing the static "variable"
>> myclass.StaticVar1
ans =
     0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer

However, if the persistent variable is static to the function (which is finally better than I first expected), how can I ensure cohesion data ?

I need the static data to be static accros the entire class.

What I could do is to declare the variable in a single function and make sure this function is called all accros the class. However, since there's no way to secure the data, it seems to be a nest for bug and maintenance issue.

I think that at the end, the second method "Static Data Object" is fitting more my need.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "cohesion data" and "secure the data"?

Comment: A static object is less secure since it will be cleared in the case of a "clearing" event -- i.e. if a reference to the handle is gone then so is your data; whereas a locked persistent function is guaranteed to be there until the end of the session or until reset manually. It's up to you if you don't like this paradigm, I was just answering the question; this is how you'd prevent a "static" variable from being cleared. :)

Comment: My point was that the object is used across multiple methods in the class. 
So I am afraid that any new developer in the project start to use it in some method in a non static way.

I will however have a look at this implementation. For the moment the SharedObject design is finally working fine, even if it's true that the object can be cleared (the only case I experienced so far is saving the file, which harden debug but is not problematic at runtime).